# What if i delete a Node in GKS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have setup GKS in free trail access.

here is screenshot of cluster
[image]

I have already setup vm instance in gce. So my kubernets cluster is having less resource for testing i have setup it but i want to know if i delete 1 node out of 3 what will happened

my pods are running in all 3 nodes(disturbed)

So i delete one node will it create a new node with deploy my running pods into another 2 nodes it will become heavy

how do i know its HA using and Scale Up and Scale Down

Please clear my questions

Answer (score 1):

> So i delete one node will it create a new node with deploy my running
> pods into another 2 nodes it will become heavy

GKE will manage the Nodes using Node pool config.

if inside your GKE you have set 3 nodes and manually remove 1 instance it will auto create new Node in cluster.

You pod might get moved to another node if space is left there or else it will go to pending state and wait for new node to join the GKE cluster.

If you want to redice nodes in GKE you have to redice minimum count in GKE node pool.

If you want to test scale up and down, you can enable auto scaling on Node pool and increase the POD count on cluster, GKE will auto add nodes. Make sure you have set correctly min and max nodes into node pool section for autoscaling.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a node, its pods are also deleted. Depending on your deployment, i.e. you have Pod scale of 3, one node will hold 2 pods and the other 1. If your app will suffer or not it depends on the actual traffic.